In .NET will a `decimal` equal to an `int` always cast to that `int`
In .NET, assuming that a decimal is not so large that it cannot be represented (or cause an overflow), will a decimal that is equal to an int always cast to the int that it is equal to ?
Same question for long.
decimal is the 128 bit floating decimal point object
int is the 32 bit integer object
long is the 64 bit integer object

It will of course throw away any decimal digits, but if it fits the range then yes (kind of the point of casting). Have you seen otherwise?

What did prevent you from testing?

@EvgeniNabokov Circular reasoning. int myInteger = int.MinValue;  for (decimal d = int.MinValue; d <= int.MaxValue; d++)  Debug.Assert((int)d == myInteger++);  The assignment to d has to be assumed to be perfect. The increment also. If I already know it's perfect then there is no reason for the cast to be imperfect.

@PoulBak I don't assume perfect representations after a cast because of precedent. They've long been imperfect when there is no alternative.  For example int i = 0x42000000 + 0x41; char c = (char)i; Console.WriteLine(c);  This displays A; not B. I think a safe assumption is that it will be perfect when possible.

You need 10 decimal digits to represent 2^31 (int) or 2^32 (uint) without loss of precision.
You need 19 decimal digits to represent 2^63 (long) and 20 decimal digits to represent 2^64 (ulong) without loss of precision.
According to IEEE 754-2019 there are 34 decimal digits in "decimal128" which is sufficient to accurately represent uint and ulong so a decimal128 representation of an integer should cast to an exactly equal integer stored as a uint or a ulong. Source  It follows that the foregoing is also true of int and long.
The .NET implementation of decimal probably supports 28 decimal digits. Source  In this case a decimal representation of an integer should also cast to an exactly equal integer stored as an int, uint, long, or ulong.
